# Java Script - cloneNode(true), clone too much items

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, appendchild, clonenode

I'll get to the point

**What am I trying?:**
I try to clone items so that every item, when clicked, clones itself. Even those that were cloned.

**Problem:**
The problem is that when I have e.g 10 items cloned, after clicking the first (original) item, it clones the next 10 items. Only the last (newest) clone, clones one element, no matter how many elements I already have.

**Info:**
Without app() at the end of the "clone" function, only the original element adds more clones.

It is problem with clondeNode() or maybe with wrong misaligned addEventListener?

Thanks for the help in advance, Matt

**JS:**

```
app = () => {
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

    divs.forEach((div) => {
        div.addEventListener('click', () => clone(event))
    })

}

clone = (event) => {
    const div = event.target;
    const clone = div.cloneNode(true);

    document.body.appendChild(clone)

    app()
}

app()
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class='div'>DIV FOR CLONING</div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: every time you call app() you add more listeners!! `addEventListener` does not replace what is there.

Comment: Where do you declare the `event` variable being used in `() => clone(event)`?

Comment: It should be `(event) => clone(event)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `app()` after a click, you add a new event listener to all existing elements, which is in addition to the handler they already had attached to them.

Instead of calling `app` there, just add the listener to the newly created clone.

Secondly, you use the same name for a function and a variable. That is confusing.

So name that variable differently:

```
const clonedDiv = div.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(clonedDiv);
clonedDiv.addEventListener('click', clone);
```

As you see, you also don't need that arrow function. Just pass `clone` as a function argument.

Comment: Great, I understand and it work as it should 
Thank You very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the clone function you are calling the app() again

```
app = () => {
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

    divs.forEach((div) => {
        div.addEventListener('click', () => clone(event))
    })

}

clone = (event) => {
    const div = event.target;
    const clone = div.cloneNode(true);

    document.body.appendChild(clone)

    app() // <<<<<<-------HERE 
}
```

that ends in a recursion, because each time you click it will add a new listener.

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-cohen-0j6dm

```
  const clone = event => {
    const div = event.target;
    const cloned = div.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(cloned);
    cloned.addEventListener("click", clone);
  };
```

Comment: Without app(), in the end of clone function, only the original element adds more clones.I want after clicking a cloned item, it also cloned itself.

Comment: Could you check 

 const clone = event => {
    const div = event.target;
    const cloned = div.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(cloned);
    cl